# Disabling Postmaster from sending emails using a config.php override

Tags: add-on, config, email, postmaster, config-overrides

Is it possible to disable Postmaster from sending emails using a config.php override? I've got a development version of a site and it'd be good if I could disable the emails from sending when I'm triggering the parcels during testing. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good feature request to add to the config. I will add this in addition to better debugging why emails won't send, and preventing error messages from displaying on live sites. All these configs vars seem relevant.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this feature doesn't exist yet (so I'm not missing something), but that you're open to adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently these features are not available in Postmaster. v1.2 is almost finished, but it wouldn't be a problem to add the following in the form a config override in the next version:

- Config var to disable all emails from being sent
- Config var to enable debugging (testing why emails are sent/not sent)
- Config var to disable all error messages (for production sites)

I use the Master Config bootstrap with multiple environment, so you can guarantee it will work for stuff like that too.

Email support[at]objectivehtml.com to get a copy of the latest beta once it's available. (A valid license is required for beta access.)

Comment: Hi Justin - did you add these config overrides to Postmaster 1.2 at all? Or is it going to be in Postmaster 1.2.x that we can look out for these? Thanks.

Comment: I did not get this in the initial 1.2 release, just too much on plate and needed to get this released (lots of people needing the docs). I don't have any ETA on this though. I might be able to get it fit in this week.

Comment: Hi Justin - no worries and no rush, I was just curious to know if it made the cut or not. When importing my live EE DB to my test environment, I've just been going to each parcel and removing the triggers to avoid emails getting sent during testing so that's my workaround.

Comment: Does anybody know if this has ever been implemented?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the webserver email option for Postmaster, why don't you just override the smtp settings based on your environment.

```
$config['mail_protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_server']      = '127.0.0.1';
$config['smtp_username']    = 'example';
$config['smtp_password']    = 'example';
```

If you're unfamiliar with multi-environment config setups, this is a good one:

https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would prefer Postmaster specific overrides (which Justin is open to, based on the comments above), but in the meantime, this seems like a good workaround, thanks.